# Active ServiceWorker doesn't ALWAYS intercept requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, service-worker

I have a React application with a ServiceWorker that has the purpose of intercepting certain requests (API calls and resource fetching) and adding an `Authorization` header with a proper token. In most of the cases it works just fine, but there are some where the service worker doesn't handle the fetch event, resulting in 401 responses.

---

**React side** ⚛️

We have the following function to register the service worker and wait for it to be active:

```js
function initializeServiceWorker() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    navigator
      .serviceWorker
      .register("/tom.js")
      .then((registration) => {

        // checks the state of the service worker until it's activated
        // and move on with the then-chain
        return pollUntil(
          (registration) => registration.active?.state === "activated",
          POLL_EVERY,      // 40ms
          registration,
          POLL_TIMEOUT     // 6000ms
        );

      })
      .then((registration) => {

        // here we send the authentication token to the service worker
        // to be stored in the IndexedDB overriding the old one
        // and persist across termination/reactivation
        registration.postMessage(<NewAuthToken>{ type: "AUTH_TOKEN", token });

      })
      .catch(reject);
  });
}
```

---

**Service Worker side**

Our service worker sets handlers for the active, install, message and fetch events as the following:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
const worker = self as any as ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;
// NOTE: we refer to self as `worker` after performing a couple of type casts


worker.addEventListener("install", () => {
  // this ensure that updates to the underlying service worker take effect
  // immediately for both the current client and all other active clients
  worker.skipWaiting();
});

worker.addEventListener("activate", async (event: ExtendableEvent) => {
  // https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#activate
  // The first activation does not connect / intercept already running clients. 
  // "claim" claims any already running clients.
  event.waitUntil(worker.clients.claim());
});

worker.addEventListener("message", (event: ExtendableMessageEvent) => {
  // here we store the token to IndexedDB
});

worker.addEventListener("fetch", (event: FetchEvent) => {
  event.respondWith(
    (async function respond() {
      try {
        const token = await DB.getToken();

        // no token - no party
        // just send the request as is
        if (!token) return fetch(event.request);

        // going somewhere else?
        // no need to add the token to the request
        const sourceHost = new URL(worker.location.origin).host;
        const destinationHost = new URL(event.request.url).host;
        if (destinationHost !== sourceHost) {
          return fetch(event.request);
        }

        // already authorized?
        // ready to go as it is
        if (event.request.headers.get("Authorization")) {
          return fetch(event.request);
        }

        /**
         * When the `destination` property of the request is empty, it means that the
         * request is an API call, otherwise it would have contained the DOM element
         * that initialized the request (image, script, style, etc.)
         *
         * In this case, we can smoothly add the token in the Headers.
         */
        if (event.request.destination === "") {
          const headers = new Headers(event.request.headers);
          headers.append("Authorization", token);
          const enhancedRequest = new Request(event.request, { headers });

          return await fetch(enhancedRequest);
        }

        // when this get executed it means the browser wants
        // the content of an <img> tag or some script or styling
        // ... but this is not the point of this SO question ...
        return requestResource(event.request, token);

      } catch (error) {
        // something horrible happen?
        // let the original request to reach it's destination freely
        return fetch(event.request);
      }
    })()
  );
});
```

---

**So, what's the issue?**

We await the `initializeServiceWorker` method before performing our first API call, like this:

```js
// in an async function...

await initializeServiceWorker();

const homeModel = await api.environment.getClientSettings();
```

In certain cases (thankfully a small percentage like <5%), the `getClientSettings` api call ends up in 401, not having the Authorization header added.

So, how is this possible? How is it possible the the `initializeServiceWorker` promise resolves before calling the api AND the token is still not there?

Does this initialization/service worker code make sense? Do you see any huge or subtle mistakes that slipped through 6 eyes already? Are we doing something kinda crazy here? ‍♂️

Let me know

---

**Strange stuff you may wonder about**

*Why do you wait until the service worker is activated?*

We noticed that, sometimes, the activation takes a little more time than necessary and that we really needed to wait it to be ready before moving on with our code.

--

*How do you know that it's not intercepting at all?*

To figure out whether we weren't adding the `Authorization` header or we weren'd intercepting the requests at all, we decided to always add an additional `X-SW` header and track on the backend the relation between the failure and the presence of this new "marker" header.

We noticed that when we receive a 401, there isn't the `X-SW` marker header, so the service worker is not touching those requests at all.

*ATTENTION: the addition of the marking header has been removed from the previous code snippet for clarity.*

--

*Can it be a race condition between the storage of the token in IndexedDB and the first API call?*

While that *can* be an issue, but it's not the case here because requests doesn't even have the `X-SW` marker header. Let's suppose that the token was not yet around in the service worker side of things, the request should anyway have the marker header, but we tracked that and it's not the case...

--

*How do you know that `initializeServiceWorker` is resolving at all?*

That call, as well as the api call, are in a try catch block that differentiates what the user sees in case of failure, depending on the failure. We know, then, that the initialization went well because we see the 401 related error message.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, there are two race conditions in your code.

First, the logic in the first part of your `initializeServiceWorker()` isn't waiting for the right thing. You're polling in an attempt to find out when the registered service worker has been activated, but even if you call `clients.claim()`, there's a gap of time between when a service worker is activated and when it takes control of all the clients in scope.

What you should be waiting for, if you want to make sure that all network requests will trigger the service worker's `fetch` handler, is for there to be a service worker in control of the current page. There's more background [in this issue](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/799), and it includes the following snippet you can use:

```js
const controlledPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
    resolve();
  } else {
    navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener(
      'controllerchange', () => resolve());
  }
});
```

Once `controlledPromise` resolves, you'll know that network requests from the current page will trigger the `fetch` handler of the service worker that's in control.

The second issue is that your `postMessage()` call completes once the `message` event is fired on the service worker, but before the IndexedDB operation actually completes.

You need to send a message back from the service worker to the client page indicating that the IndexedDB write has completed. You can do this with "vanilla" JavaScript using [`MessagePort`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessagePort), but I'd recommend using the [Comlink library](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/comlink) instead, as this will wrap up the details of using `postMessage()` and coordinating `MessagePort`s in a nicer, promise-based interface.

Comment: First of all, thank you a lot Jeff. I read the issue that you mentioned and I think I got the point of waiting for the page to be controlled before resolving in my case.

The second issue you mention is more related to my "negligency" writing down the question. We actually have a message exchange there where we wait for an `AUTH_TOKEN_ACKN` message to come back before moving on. Good point anyway.

So, I'm gonna integrate this promise in our flow replacing the polling and release.
I'll let you know if this solves our issue for good and mark this as the accepted answer.

Thank you again.

Comment: We gathered some more data via our insights platform. I have to sadly say that replacing the awaiting for the service worker to be active through the polling, with the handling of the event that happens when it takes control of the page has worsened our situation, as we tracked far more 401 errors than before. We noticed that sometimes the promise is resolved immediately because `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` is around but then going in 401 in a split second. My question would be: is it possible that we should ALSO wait for the service worker to be active? Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Do you have a different service worker that's also registered for the scope of your web app, but which doesn't perform the auth stuff you're trying to do? If `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` is set, there's an active service worker in control of the current page, and `navigator.serviceWorker.controller.scriptURL` contains the URL of the specific SW script. Maybe an unexpected legacy SW script is in control?

Comment: Mhmm we checked but no, we don't have any other service worker active controlling the page. We also added back the polling for activation and we measured a reduction of the number of errors, but still quite a bit of 401s.

Comment: Well, the best I can say is that if `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` is set, the `fetch` handler of your SW is triggered whenever a network request is made from a page. What you're describing may point to a bug in the logic inside of your SW.